# Strong immutability vs weak immutability in Java?

Tags: java

In a Java interview Q&A list I have, it says that, in Java you can make an object immutable in three ways. One of the ways is:

> Ensure that methods can't be overridden by either making the class
>   final (Strong Immutability) or making your methods final (Weak
>   immutability).

How is it that making methods final is considered less immutable than making the class final? Also, what is meant by strong immutability and weak immutability ?

Comment: The subclass could have extra fields which could be changed.

Comment: Note though that true immutability isn't possible in Java, not unless you promise not to use `synchronized` on any of your business objects, only on dedicated lock objects.

Comment: Also, there is a third way (sort of): you don't make your class final but you provide no public constructors.

Comment: @pbabcdefp While it is true, I am not sure if that really is a problem. Lets say we have `class A` which is weak immutable. And we created `class B extends A` which has new mutable fields. In code like `A a = new B()`, for `a` reference its value is still immutable, because `B` couldn't change anything which `a` has access to (except maybe protected fields, but if they exist I am not sure if `A` can be called immutable). We are sure that all methods which `a` can use will have same functionality because these methods are final. In other words scope available for `a` will still be immutable.

Comment: @Pshemo It really is a problem if you're using these objects in a multi-threaded environment. Though as you rightly point out, the bit of the state of `B` that is defined in `A` will be untroubled, it's just the extra bits that can go out of sync.

Comment: @Pshemo: See the counter-example at the end of my answer.

Comment: This is a relatively useless definition of 'immutable'. From a functional programming / concurrent programming standpoint, the issue is not what you can do with a subclass, but whether all the fields are 'final'.

Comment: Another problem is that if objects `a` and `b` are immutable and `a.equals(b)`, it's reasonable to expect them to be interchangeable.

Comment: @bmargulies ...but in Java, fields being final does not prevent them from changing their state. It only prevents reassigning them. So you would have to somehow require all fields to be final *and* immutable, but there is no way to enforce that if you allow subclassing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) states that a subclass instance can be substituted wherever a superclass instance is expected, without changing the semantics from the caller's point-of-view.  A subclass could introduce mutable behaviour, thus violating the LSP.

On the one hand, final methods (and private member variables) limit the scope for altering the semantics as seen directly via the superclass interface.  On the other hand, a mutable subclass could introduce violations indirectly.

For example, perhaps the caller framework doesn't bother cloning or using synchronisation in multi-threaded scenarios, based on the immutability assumption.  This would cause major issues when applied to a mutable subclass, but not due to any semantic change to the superclass interface.

Answer (score 0):

Making a class final ensures that you cannot subclass it which means that the class is not open for extension. Immutability is not all about saving the initial state of an object but also to ensure that there should be no behavioral change.

But if a class is not marked final then there is always a possibility to subclass it and alter its implementation and we know that a parent reference can refer a child object. So there is a possibility of violation of immutability.

Comment: Behavioural change is fine, so long as that behaviour is *also* immutable.

Comment: If we are saying that behavior is immutable then it simply means that it should not change.

Comment: But it's the *objects* that are immutable.